# stop pandas from renaming columns with same name so i can use wide to long

Tags: pandas

I have an excel file that im reading into pandas that looks similar to this

```
name        size    color   material        size    color   material    size    color   material
bob         m       red     coton           m         yellow  cotton      m         green   dri-fit
james       l       green   dri-fit         l         green   cotton      l         red     cotton
steve       l       green   dri-fit         l         green   cotton      l         red     cotton
```

I want to tally all my shirt types into something like this

```
l green dri-fit   2
l red   coton     2
m red   coton     1
```

i am using pandas ExcelFile to read the file into a file object, then using parse to parse the sheet into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.ExcelFile('myexcelfile.xlsx')
df = file.parse('sheet1')
```

To try and get to my desired output, I am trying to use Wide to Long. The problem is, because some of my columns have the same names, when I read the file into pandas its renaming my columns. The second instance of size, for example, turns automatically into size.2, same with color and material. If i try to use stubnames with wide to long, it complains that the first instance of size ... "stubname cant be identical to a column name".

Is there any way to use wide to long prior to pandas renaming my columns?

Comment: take a glance at my second paragraph - pandas is renaming all my columns so I dont have just color, material, and size. I have material.3, material.4, color.2, etc

Answer (score 2):

The column numbering is problematic for `pd.wide_to_long`, so we need to modify the first instance of the column names, adding a `.0`, so they don't conflict with the stubs.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard() 
print(df)

    name size  color material size.1 color.1 material.1 size.2 color.2 material.2
0    bob    m    red    coton      m  yellow     cotton      m   green    dri-fit
1  james    l  green  dri-fit      l   green     cotton      l     red     cotton
2  steve    l  green  dri-fit      l   green     cotton      l     red     cotton
```

#### Code:

```
stubs = ['size', 'color', 'material']
d = {x: f'{x}.0' for x in stubs}
df.columns = [d.get(k, k) for k in df.columns]

res = pd.wide_to_long(df, i='name', j='num', sep='.', stubnames=stubs)
#          size   color material
#name  num                      
#bob   0      m     red    coton
#james 0      l   green  dri-fit
#steve 0      l   green  dri-fit
#bob   1      m  yellow   cotton
#james 1      l   green   cotton
#steve 1      l   green   cotton
#bob   2      m   green  dri-fit
#james 2      l     red   cotton
#steve 2      l     red   cotton

res.groupby([*res]).size()
#size  color   material
#l     green   cotton      2
#              dri-fit     2
#      red     cotton      2
#m     green   dri-fit     1
#      red     coton       1
#      yellow  cotton      1
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `value_counts`

```
cols = ['size', 'color', 'material']
s = pd.value_counts([*zip(*map(np.ravel, map(df.get, cols)))])

(l, red, cotton)       2
(l, green, cotton)     2
(l, green, dri-fit)    2
(m, green, dri-fit)    1
(m, yellow, cotton)    1
(m, red, coton)        1
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `Counter`

And more to my liking

```
from collections import Counter

s = pd.Series(Counter([*zip(*map(np.ravel, map(df.get, cols)))]))
s.rename_axis(['size', 'color', 'material']).reset_index(name='freq')

  size   color material  freq
0    m     red    coton     1
1    m  yellow   cotton     1
2    m   green  dri-fit     1
3    l   green  dri-fit     2
4    l   green   cotton     2
5    l     red   cotton     2
```

Comment: since my column names are not all the same because pandas keeps renaming them, when I run your code I get zero counts, but If i change cols to all the columns in question .. i think its working. ['Size 1', 'Size 2' ... 'color', 'color.1', 'color.2' ... etc]. Is this the right approach I should take ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

CODE BELOW:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/me/Desktop/sovrflw_data.xlsx')
df.drop('name', axis=1, inplace=True)
arr = df.values.reshape(-1, 3)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['size','color','material'])
df2['count']=1
df2.groupby(['size','color','material'],as_index=False).count()
```